# ColdFusion giving "template denied access" error using cfajaxproxy

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I need an cfajaxproxy interface to my server (to pass it data without having to do a submit on a page).  Hopefully cfajaxproxy is the correct way to go?

To learn this, I first modified an example tutorial shown at http://tutorial13.learncf.com/, but after getting an "template denied access" error, I decided to simply use the tutorial directly as is, which just has two small files (that can be cut and pasted right from his tutorial).  Unfortunately I get the same error with his tutorial (even though he has it running on his site as a demo).  So ??

I'm putting the proxy.cfc file right in the (main) wwwroot directory I am accessing (first time using a cfc).   Do I need to ask the hosting company to allow something on the server  (which is running ColdFusion 8)?

Thanks.    Error Details are:

Error Occurred While Processing Request
Security: The requested template has been denied access to C:/Coldfusion8/wwwroot/WEB-INF/cfclasses/cfproxy2ecfc771136334.class.

The following is the internal exception message: access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:/Coldfusion8/wwwroot/WEB-INF/cfclasses/cfproxy2ecfc771136334.class read)

```
ColdFusion cannot determine the line of the template that caused this error. This is often    caused by an error in the exception handling subsystem.
Resources:
Check the ColdFusion documentation to verify that you are using the correct syntax.
Search the Knowledge Base to find a solution to your problem.
Browser     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko)    Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17
Remote Address      72.201.113.149
Referrer    
Date/Time   22-Feb-13 12:42 AM
Stack Trace
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission    C:/Coldfusion8/wwwroot/WEB-INF/cfclasses/cfproxy2ecfc771136334.class read) at  cfdemo2ecfm1260454926.runPage(C:/Websites/202350mu7/wwwroot/sf/demo.cfm:1) 

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:\Coldfusion8\wwwroot\WEB-INF\cfclasses\cfproxy2ecfc771136334.class read)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:871)
             ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a security sandbox issue, you need to contact your host and make sure you have a sandbox with access to this folder.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you tell me if I should put this cfc in a sub-folder, and if so, if this affects any of the CF tags to access it.  (Does the server search the entire directory tree of components and subdirectories not make a difference in the tag)?